# Windows 10 Pro Taskbar settings

Tags: windows-10

First of all, I have a GTX 1660 and a GTX 1050 GPU's installed on my desktop. I also have the desktop icons in hide mode. I have them moved to the taskbar. The two settings that the taskbar is turned on are the auto hide and always on top.

I just updated widows a few days ago. And now I can not find the setting "always on top" under Taskbar settings. Why does Microsoft remove this setting in widows 10?

Comment: I see that here. Just the evolution of Windows.

Comment: Is the taskbar ever not “on top”? I, too, do not recall such an option.

Answer (score 0):

The option is still there in Taskbar settings, just changed a name
(in truth, I don't recall ever seeing an option for "Always on top").

The option is called
"Automatically hide the taskbar in desktop mode feature".

Turn Off this option, and the taskbar will always be on top,
as long as your computer is in desktop mode (does not apply to Tablet mode).